# Mysql SELECT with WHERE clause not working with variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, select, where-clause

I am pulling my hair out. I have two SELECT statements that are basically the same principal. The first one is working and the second one will not work with the WHERE clause in it. I need some fresh eyes and suggestions. I have been on every forum and read every post and have tried many "solutions" to no avail.  Hoping someone will see something I have missed.

```
$oID = zen_db_prepare_input($_GET['oID']);

  // Color coding for invoice -Start queries---

  $query = "SELECT * FROM cart1_orders WHERE orders_id = $oID";
  $result = $db->Execute($query); 
  $shiploc = $result->fields['shipping_method'];
  if ($result->RecordCount() > 0) { 
  echo 'Test Query: = ' . $result->fields['shipping_method']; 
  } else { 
  echo 'Sorry, no record found for product number ' ; 
  }  

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart1_store_locations  WHERE pickup_name= $shiploc";
  $results = $db->Execute($sql); 
  $newcolorblock = $results->fields['color_code'];
  if ($results->RecordCount() > 0) { 
  echo 'Color Query: = ' . $results->fields['color_code'];
  echo 'Location: = '. $results->fields['pickup_name']; 
  } else { 
  echo 'Sorry, no record found for Color Code ' ; 
  }
```

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions hopefully you will be able to see something I can't.

First query results: Test Query: = Store Pickup (Mooresville - Gold's Gym)
Second query results: WARNING: An Error occurred, please refresh the page and try again.

If the WHERE clause is removed it returns values but not the correct ones. I need the WHERE statement for it to pull the correct information.

**ANSWER** kindly provided by bloodyKnuckles :)

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM cart1_store_locations WHERE pickup_name= $shiploc";
```

changed to: (Needed to be escaped to comp for 's in the table data)

```
$shiploc_escaped = mysql_escape_string($shiploc);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cart1_store_locations  WHERE pickup_name=       '".$shiploc_escaped."'";
```

I have not used this forum before. LOVE IT!!! Thank you everyone!

Comment: Is `$shiploc` a string? It appears you're treating it as an integer (not quoted).

Comment: Yes, should be a string. I have tried single quotes with it and that doesn't work either.

Comment: You really should learn about SQL joins and parameterised statements.

Comment: Yes, I tried a join with this as well and could not get that to work either. This actually produced better results so far so I have stuck with it. I do plan to play with joins a bit more after this project. I just need this to work...like now. lol

Comment: Quote and escape your data. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your string has a single quote in it:

> Store Pickup (Mooresville - Gold's Gym)

...you need to escape the variable `$shiploc`:

```
$shiploc_escaped = addslashes($shiploc);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cart1_store_locations  WHERE pickup_name= '".$shiploc_escaped."'";
```

Reading up on [Zen Cart Escaping Content](http://www.zen-cart.com/wiki/index.php/Developers_-_Database#Escaping_Content), it appears this is an option:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cart1_store_locations  WHERE pickup_name= '".$db->prepare_input($shiploc)."'";
```

...and, better yet, this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cart1_store_locations WHERE pickup_name= :pickup_name:";
$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':pickup_name:', $shiploc, 'string');
```

Comment: I want to KISS you!!!! That worked thank you! One question... I am pretty certain that zen cart uses mysqli so that is what I have been using in custom pages. Is that not the case? Do you know?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php requires connection be passed to that function. `mysqli_real_escape_string($shiploc)` will fail.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: @kngiggles You're welcome, but the answer needs to reflect the change to that function. Otherwise, future visitors may not know what to do, if comments should happen to disappear.

Comment: @bloody... OP is using `mysqli_`, that edit you made `mysql_escape_string($shiploc)` will fail. Those different APIs do not intermix with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$shiploc` might be `null`. Before second query please write `var_dump($shiploc);` and let us know what you get.

**EDIT**

```
$oID = zen_db_prepare_input($_GET['oID']);

  // Color coding for invoice -Start queries---

  $query = "SELECT * FROM cart1_orders WHERE orders_id = $oID";
  $result = $db->Execute($query); 
  $shiploc = $result->fields['shipping_method'];
  if ($result->RecordCount() > 0) { 
  echo 'Test Query: = ' . $result->fields['shipping_method']; 
  } else { 
  echo 'Sorry, no record found for product number ' ; 
  }  

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart1_store_locations  WHERE pickup_name= '".$shiploc."'";
  $results = $db->Execute($sql); 
  $newcolorblock = $results->fields['color_code'];
  if ($results->RecordCount() > 0) { 
  echo 'Color Query: = ' . $results->fields['color_code'];
  echo 'Location: = '. $results->fields['pickup_name']; 
  } else { 
  echo 'Sorry, no record found for Color Code ' ; 
  }
```

Comment: string(39) "Store Pickup (Mooresville - Gold's Gym)"   This is the result. Exactly how it should show.

Comment: so it is a string...therfore you nees to use single quotes between `$shiploc` check my answer. I am going to edit it

Comment: I have already tried single quotes and I still get the error. '$shiploc'

Comment: try my answer please `'".$shiploc."'"`  Copy and paste my answer, and it will work

Comment: I have tried that combo as well.  Let me give it another go. Will let you know.

Comment: your `Gold's` is killing it :)

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM cart1_store_locations  WHERE pickup_name= '".addslashes($shiploc_escaped)."'";`